# XMPP SDK in .net that's not abandoned

Tags: c#, .net, xmpp, xmppframework

I am looking for an SDK to send XMPP messages that are up to do date and support the latest RFCs of the XMPP protocol.

I know about the new framework by AG SOFTWARE but this costs over 1000 euros per developer seat.

I have checked the XMPP site but found nothing of interest.

Answer (score 0):

Try [XMPP/Media Library for .NET and Windows Phone 7.5](http://xmedianet.codeplex.com/). Hope it is robust enough.

Answer (score 0):

There is also agsXMPP SDK from AG-Software which is GPL. And there is jabber-net which is LGPL. Both products are up to date with the RFCs and supported.